# Interactive Selection highlighting of text inside the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, highlight, interactive

what I need is interactive selection highlighting of text in the browser via Javascript.

To be more specific, lets just say I have a bunch of text in a `div` element like so:

```
<div>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog ... </div>
```

Now what I want to do is to select a certain range of this text and highlight it (i.e. "brown fox"). I already got that working by using `rangy.js`.

Now I really want to make this selection / highlight more interactive so that the user can grab the beginning or the end of the selection (with some kind of handle) and resize the selection interactively by dragging the beginning or the end of the current selection to a new starting or endpoint.

I tried to google for this but couldn't find anything. Whats even worse is that I habe absolutely no idea how I should start to implement something like this.

Perhaps can someone can point me into the right direction or even better already has some idea on how to start implementing something like this.

Thanks a lot for any help ...

Comment: It sounds like you are wanting to reproduce mobile style highlighting in the desktop browser.  Am I right?

Comment: Well I don't know what you mean by "mobile style highlighting" but if it behaves exactly as described above, then yes.

Comment: When you highlight a string of text in Android for example, you will get handles on either side of the selection which you can drag to modify the existing selection.  It may provide you with a hint as the direction to look in for your answer as developers have clearly solved this problem on other platforms, so you may want to start there.  Whether or not there is a JS lib for it is another story. Here's a google image search  https://www.google.com/search?q=android+text+selection+handles&espv=2&biw=1438&bih=702&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=jQP5VJyhLoKggwTJ3oG4Bw&sqi=2&ved=0CDkQsAQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is rather complex and hampered by the lack of conformity across browsers. However, I have had a stab at the problem with some level of success.

## [Test out my solution with this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ninjakannon/z5t7L663/21/)

I provide no guarantees that this works in all situations, my testing has been limited to text alone so far. There are also a few issues that need fixing, which I will address in the near future. However, I think it's ready to post here.

### Methodology

The problem can be broken down into several steps. First, we need to insert markers around the user's selection. This is not too difficult, although there are several design decisions that must be addressed. After some experimentation, I settled on inserting spans directly into the document at the marker positions; it is then easier to select content between these markers. Below is the insert marker method.

```
function insertMarker (isBefore) {
    var range;
    
    if (window.getSelection) {
        // IE9+ and non-IE
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        
        if (sel.getRangeAt) {
            range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            range.collapse(isBefore);
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        // IE < 9
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.collapse(isBefore);
    }
    
    // Create the marker element and insert it into the DOM.
    if (range) {
        range.insertNode(createMarker(isBefore));
    }
}
```

Second, the user must be able to drag these markers around the document such that they lock between characters/selectable content. This can be achieved using `document.caretPositionFromPoint(x, y)` (standard) or `document.caretRangeFromPoint(x, y)` (WebKit).

Third, when the markers are moved, the selection must be updated to reflect this change. This can be achieved using `range.setStartAfter` and `range.setEndBefore`, which each are supported in most browsers, despite varying Range implementations.

```
function selectSelection () {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        // IE9+ and non-IE
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.setStartAfter($(".marker").get(0));
        range.setEndBefore($(".marker").get(1));
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
    else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        // IE < 9
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.setStartAfter($(".marker").get(0));
        range.setEndBefore($(".marker").get(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

html

```
<div id="selectable"></div>
<br />
<hr />
<button id="clear">clear selections</button>
<hr />
<br />
<div id="selections">
  <div class="selected"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#selectable .ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
}
#selectable .ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}
#selections {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
#clear {
  position: relative;
  left: calc(37%);
}
.selected {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.selected,
.text {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
}
.ui-widget-content {
  border: 1px dotted rgba(170, 170, 170, .25);
}
.ui-widget-conent span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

js

```
  var selectable = $("#selectable") // selectable words
  , selections = $("#selections") // selected words container parent
  , selected = $(".selected") // selected words container
  , clear = $("#clear") // clear all
  , sel = ".ui-selected" // selected word
  , content = ".ui-widget-content" // selectable words element `class`
  , text = ".text" // selected words draggable, resizable container `class`
  , handles = {} // resize handles
  , str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog ..." // text, `string`
    // split `str`, return array of words
  , words = str.split(" ").map(function(word, i) {
      $("<span />", {
        "class": content.slice(1),
        "text": word,
        "css": {
          "margin": "2px"
        }
      }).appendTo(selectable)
    });
  // append `handles` to `text` container
  $.each(["nw", "ne", "sw", "se"], function(_, handle) {
    var elem = $("<div />", {
        "class": "ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-" + handle,
        "css": {
          "width": "calc(12px + 5%)",
          "height": "calc(12px + 5%)",
          "border-radius": "50%",
          "background": "#000"
        }
      })
      .appendTo(selected)
      .parent().find(":last")
      .css({
        "right": "-5px",
        "bottom": "-5px"
      });
    handles[handle] = elem[0];
  });
  // `selected` settings
  // set `selected` `display` to `none`
  selected
  .hide(0)
  .resizable({
      handles: handles
  })
  .draggable({
      containment: "parent"
  });
  // collect selected words at `selectable.data("selections", [])` array,
  // append words to `text`,
  // append `text` to `selected`,
  // set `selected` `display` to `block`
  selectable.data("selections", [])
    .selectable({
      selected: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).data("selections").push($(ui.selected).text())
      },
      stop: function() {
        selected
          .find(".text")
          .remove()
          .addBack()
          .prepend(
            $("<div />", {
              "class": "text",
              "text": $(this).data("selections").join(" "),
              "css": {
                "position": "relative",
                "display": "block",
                "padding": "calc(15%)",
                "height": "calc(50%)",
                "white-space": "pre-line",
                "overflow": "hidden"
              }
            })
          ).show(0)
      }
    });
  // remove selected words from `selectable.data("selections", [])` array,
  // remove `sel` `class` from `selectable` words,
  // remove `text`,
  // set `selected` display to `none`
  clear.on("click", function(e) {
    selectable.data("selections", [])
      .find(sel).removeClass(sel.slice(1));
    selections.find(text).remove()
      .addBack().find(selected).hide(0)
  });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/dpt9bn0n/

See jQuery UI [Selectable](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/) , [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) , [Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/)

```js
$(function() {

  var selectable = $("#selectable") // selectable words
  , selections = $("#selections") // selected words container parent
  , selected = $(".selected") // selected words container
  , clear = $("#clear") // clear all
  , sel = ".ui-selected" // selected word
  , content = ".ui-widget-content" // selectable words element `class`
  , text = ".text" // selected words draggable, resizable container `class`
  , handles = {} // resize handles
  , str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog ..." // text, `string`
    // split `str`, return array of words
  , words = str.split(" ").map(function(word, i) {
      $("<span />", {
        "class": content.slice(1),
        "text": word,
        "css": {
          "margin": "2px"
        }
      }).appendTo(selectable)
    });
  // append `handles` to `text` container
  $.each(["nw", "ne", "sw", "se"], function(_, handle) {
    var elem = $("<div />", {
        "class": "ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-" + handle,
        "css": {
          "width": "calc(12px + 5%)",
          "height": "calc(12px + 5%)",
          "border-radius": "50%",
          "background": "#000"
        }
      })
      .appendTo(selected)
      .parent().find(":last") // `se` 
      .css({
        "right": "-5px",
        "bottom": "-5px"
      });
    handles[handle] = elem[0];
  });
  // `selected` settings
  // set `selected` `display` to `none`
  selected
    .hide(0)
    .resizable({
      handles: handles
    })
    .draggable({
      containment: "parent"
    });
  // collect selected words at `selectable.data("selections", [])` array,
  // append words to `text`,
  // append `text` to `selected`,
  // set `selected` `display` to `block`
  selectable.data("selections", [])
    .selectable({
      selected: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).data("selections").push($(ui.selected).text())
      },
      stop: function() {
        selected
          .find(".text")
          .remove()
          .addBack()
          .prepend(
            $("<div />", {
              "class": "text",
              "text": $(this).data("selections").join(" "),
              "css": {
                "position": "relative",
                "display": "block",
                "padding": "calc(15%)",
                "height": "calc(50%)",
                "white-space": "pre-line",
                "overflow": "hidden"
              }
            })
          ).show(0)
      }
    });
  // remove selected words from `selectable.data("selections", [])` array,
  // remove `sel` `class` from `selectable` words,
  // remove `text`,
  // set `selected` display to `none`
  clear.on("click", function(e) {
    selectable.data("selections", [])
      .find(sel).removeClass(sel.slice(1));
    selections.find(text).remove()
      .addBack().find(selected).hide(0)
  });

  // do stuff
  var phrase = [0, 1, 2, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 9];
  setTimeout(function() {
    $.when(
        selectable.queue("phrase", $.map(phrase, function(word, i) {
          return function(next) {
            return $.when(!$(this).find(content).eq(word)
              .addClass("ui-selecting").parent()
              .data("ui-selectable")._mouseStop(false) && $(this)
            ).then(function(el) {
              return el.delay(2000);
            }).then(next)
          }
        })
        )
        .dequeue("phrase").promise("phrase")
      , clear
    )
    .then(function(el, button) {
        button.trigger("click")
    });
  }, 2713);

});
```

```css
#selectable .ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
}
#selectable .ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}
#selections {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
#clear {
  position: relative;
  left: calc(37%);
}
.selected {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.selected,
.text {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
}
.ui-widget-content {
  border: 1px dotted rgba(170, 170, 170, .25);
}
.ui-widget-conent span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" 
      rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="selectable"></div>
<br />
<hr />
<button id="clear">clear selections</button>
<hr />
<br />
<div id="selections">
  <div class="selected"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks a lot for your input. Sadly this is not really what I was thinking about. I am searching for a way to resize the selection itself, not a separate text area where the selected elements are displayed. 

The last comment from robabby above pretty much sums up what I am searching for. Here is the [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+text+selection+handles&espv=2&biw=1438&bih=702&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=jQP5VJyhLoKggwTJ3oG4Bw&sqi=2&ved=0CDkQsAQ) again of how it should look.

Comment: @evermean Resize selected `element `,  `font-size` , or both ?

Comment: I don't care about the font-size, I need to select a certain part of a text and be able to resize this selection afterwards (...exactly as shown on the linked pictures above.).

Comment: By resize , resize only `element` content-box ? i.e.g., same or similar to draggable element at piece above, though at the point of selection add resizable "handles" to selection ?

Comment: This is how it should work. [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uwhzo4bT4hE). The relevant part starts at 0:30 ... hope this helps clarify it.