# when clicking on highlighted text, How to show left and right markers so user can grab them and adjust the highlight in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

[image]

if i want to show left and right markers to extend the highlight of already highlighted text, what approach can be used in web(javascript/jquery/react). please suggest. i could not find any approach after a week of analysis.

```
function highlightText() {
     var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var newNode = document.createElement("mark");
    range.surroundContents(newNode);

 }
```

Comment: There are a few solutions here, did you try those? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28820551/interactive-selection-highlighting-of-text-inside-the-browser

Comment: I tried checking this one and it does not seem to work. trying to figure it. Thanks much for sharing!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getSelectedText() {
    var selectedText = '';
    if (window.getSelection) {
        selectedText = window.getSelection();
    }else if (document.getSelection) {
        selectedText = document.getSelection();
    }else if (document.selection) {
        selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text;
    } else return;

    document.testform.selectedtext.value = selectedText;
}
```

```html
<p>Select any part of this sentence and press the button</p>

<input type="button" value="Get Selection" onmousedown="getSelectedText()">
 
<form name="testform">
    <textarea name="selectedtext" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>
</form>
```